# fastcgi_param and log output with $request_id

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

I see that in the nginx core module one of the variables is [$request_id](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_id).

1) How can I pass that variable to my Fastcgi script with fastcgi_param (or without, now that I think about it)? The following directive does not work:

```
fastcgi_param REQUEST_ID $request_id;
```

That directive just gives this error when nginx is restarted:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown "request_id" variable
```

2) How can I output that same variable in the access and error logs?

Comment: Are you using at least 1.11.0?

Comment: This is my nginx version:

    # nginx -v
    nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)

I'm hesitant to use a newer version than is the default for my Ubuntu
distribution. Is it necessary to upgrade to 1.11.0 to get this functinality?

Comment: Upgrade to at least 1.11.0.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that.